# set Flash.keepMessage to true in JSF 2 configuration file is possible?

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, message, flash-scope

This line:

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getFlash().setKeepMessages(true);
```

Can be changed by another code in any configuration files? I want to avoid typing this line whenever I need to redirect from code whit this line:

```
     FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect("errorApp");
```

Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no configuration setting to change the "keep messages" feature.

Just create an utility method which replaces the repeated code by a single method call. E.g.

```
public static void addGlobalInfoFlashMessage(String message) {
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    context.getExternalContext().getFlash().setKeepMessages(true);
    context.addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, message, null));
}
```

Comment: It is possible to create a thread? That it is execute the first time in the web application and it is work for all users?