# How to deal with JSF messages between page navigations (POST-REDIRECT-GET)

Tags: jsf-2

I'm developing **JSF 2** web application and using implicit navigation from page to page specifying outcome values and changing url values. I also have some Ajax requests to be able to make changes in some pages without having to submit everything.

My problem comes when, for example, I edit a user's data and save the changes. Managed Bean saves user data and return an String to navigate to the user list. When user is properly saved, a `FacesMessage` is added before the action method finishes.

**Button**

```xhtml
<p:commandButton value="#{msg.UPDATE}" action="#{manager.actionSave}"
            ajax="false" />
```

**Code into the method**

```java
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(clientId, 
    new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, msg, msg));
```

However, and even I have an `<h:messages />` tag in my main page, nothing is displayed there.

Comment: You'll need to persist the messages yourself in the flash scope. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10369601)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Passing a FacesMessage to the next page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12481506/passing-a-facesmessage-to-the-next-page)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem symptoms suggests that you're navigating by a redirect instead of a (default) forward by either the `faces-redirect=true` parameter in the outcome, or the `<redirect/>` entry in the navigation case, if you're still using legacy navigation rules in `faces-config.xml`.

Faces messages are request scoped and are thus only available in the resource served by the current request. When navigating by a redirect, you're basically instructing the webbrowser to create a brand new request on the given URL. The faces messages are not available in that request at all.

If redirecting is really mandatory, e.g. to accomplish the [POST-Redirect-GET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) pattern — which is a Good Thing —, then you need to store the message in the flash scope. You can do that by calling [`Flash#setKeepMessages()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/Flash.html#setKeepMessages%28boolean%29), passing `true`.

```
context.addMessage(clientId, message);
context.getExternalContext().getFlash().setKeepMessages(true);
```

Note that this will fail if you're using a Mojarra version older than 2.1.14 and are redirecting to a resource in a different base folder. See also [issue 2136](http://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-2136).

Comment: That's the right way, thanks @BalusC. By the way, is there a way to do it from a configuration file or something like that? Basically to prevent calling the method for every single message I add.

Comment: There's nothing. Just use an utility class for this. OmniFaces offers [`Messages`](https://showcase-omnifaces.rhcloud.com/showcase/utils/Messages.xhtml) class for this. E.g. `Messages.addFlashInfo(clientId, msg);`

Comment: Will give it a try. Just wanted to point that as I'm using PrettyFaces for navigation, it's always according to the POST-Redirect-GET pattern.

http://ocpsoft.org/support/prettyfaces-users/how-to-do-post-redirect-get-after-action-with-prettyfaces